# What is the expected time to A reach C, given the probabilities and travel time?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

A space ship walks randomly between 3 planets: A. B and C. It does countless trips among then, always going from planet X to planet Y. The probabilities (are constants) and travel times are on the table below. Example: leaving from planet B, there is a 50% chance that it arrives on planet A, and 50% at planet B (yes, it can go back to the same place it left). ORIGIN (row) DESTINY (columns)

The problem: there is a space ship leving from A that will only stop the journey when it reaches C. What will be the expected mean time (in months) to reach C?

| PROBABILITY MATRIX | DESTINATION |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORIGIN | **A** | **B** | **C** |
| **A** | 0.05 | 0.90 | 0.05 |
| **B** | 0.50 | 0.50 | 0 |
| **C** | 0 | 0 | 1 |

| TRAVEL TIME MATRIX (in moths) | DESTINATION |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORIGIN | **A** | **B** | **C** |
| **A** | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| **B** | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| **C** | 0 | 0 | 0 |

[markov chain sketch with the probabilities and travel time][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTKz7.png

What I have so far:

let "a" be the number of times it will bounce on a journey from A to C;
"b", the number of times it will bounce on a journey from B to C; and
"c", the number of times it will bounce on a journey from C to C.

a = 1 + 0.05a + 0.9b + 0.05c (c is the absorbing state, so c=0)

thus:  a = 1 + 0.05a + 0.9b

b = 1+ 0.5a + 0.5b

I came up with a = 56 and b = 58.

BUT, these numbers represents the number of times it moves from one planet to another. It does not give me the times in months that I need. (I'm stuck here)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Side note:  by "destiny" I think you mean "destination".

Comment: @lulu yes hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do essentially the same thing by taking the travel time into account?  Let $m_A$ be the expected number of months of the journey if the ship is at $A$, and let $m_b$ be the expected number of months if the ship is at $B$.

Then we have $$m_A=.05(5+m_A)+.9(2+m_B)+.05\cdot10$$  We get a similar equation for $m_B$, and solve for $m_A$ and $m_B$.  Then $m_A$ is the answer to the question.